# Python -- TypeError: format() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, format

I'm taking an intro course to Python3 by SoloLearn.
This is a code example they give, but when I run it in Python3 or in Python2, I get similar errors. Here's the code, on introduction to String Formatting:

```
nums = [4, 5, 6]
msg = "Numbers: {0} {1} {2}".
format(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2])
print(msg)
```

which is supposed to result in:

```
>>>
Numbers: 4 5 6
>>>
```

But I get a **Syntax Error** on line 2, which points to the "." at the end of the line as being an invalid use of syntax.

And I get the **TypeError: format() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)** 
when I try to execute line 3.

Why!?

Answer (score 4):

Lines 2 and 3 should be one line:

```
msg = "Numbers: {0} {1} {2}".format(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2])
```

If the code had that line break in the actual course, they need to get their act together. If you introduced the line break, don't do that.

Comment: Hah! Thank you, that seems very obvious now.
I didn't introduce the line break. Interestingly, with the line break included, the code runs fine on the virtual python environment they offer.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the `format` in another line, you either have to put a backslash like this:

```
msg = "Numbers: {0} {1} {2}".\
format(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2])
```

or wrap it with parenthesis, or better yet, put the `format` in the same line